# How to customize record detail page of object for salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, page-layout, tab

I have below layout in Salesforce1,
I want to add new tab after related tab with a custom lightning component.

[image]

I tried to update page page layout from Lightning App Builder as below,

[image]

but it is not getting reflected in Salesforce1, am I missing out something?

Comment: Could you please try with re-arrange tab order. Like, first Custom Tab then rest of the tab

Comment: @SubhasisKar I tried to rearrange but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## [How Page Layouts Work in the Salesforce Mobile App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=layouts_in_salesforce1.htm&type=5)
>
> Use the enhanced page layout editor to customize the layout of an
> object’s record detail pages, configure actions, and adjust which
> fields and related lists appear in the Salesforce mobile app.
>
> In the Salesforce mobile app, page layouts drive these areas of the
> mobile experience. Record Related Information and Detail Pages
>
> When you view a record in the mobile app, you see the fields,
> Visualforce pages, and related lists that are based on the record type
> and the user’s profile. Related lists show up as single-line cards
> containing the name of the page or related list. Tapping the related
> list card displays its details.
>
> **Mobile Cards**
>
> You can add expanded lookups, components, canvas apps, and Visualforce
> pages to the Mobile Cards section of your page layout to have them
> show up as mobile cards in the mobile app. The elements you place in
> this section don’t show up on a record’s detail page in the full
> Salesforce site. They appear only on the record’s related information
> page in the mobile app.

Comment: it works for me thanks! I can add it to mobile cards.